# multiple post ajax to different methods in the same controller

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, spring-mvc, post

I am newbie for jquery, js, java, etc all this world. I am using spring mvc maven.

I have a jsp file with two post functions with different url which is matching with two different methods in same controller.

so I expected =>

- `caseAsend` (in myTest.jsp) posts data to `caseAHandler` (in myController.java)
- `caseBend` (in myTest.jsp) posts data to `caseBHandler` (in myController.java)

but both `caseAsend`and `caseBsend` ends up to the same handler in myController.java

[note] `caseAsend`, `caseBsend` are called by different behaviors in jsp file and also need to process differently in controller. so it should be handled seperately

**[Q] How can I make 1:1 mapping between `post ajax` and `handling method` in myController.java.**
why both posts goes to the same method even with different url?

[My code is like this] :

1)  myTest.jsp

```
function caseAsend(title, id){     
    $.ajax({
            url:'/test/{caseA}.html',
            data: 'title='+title+'&id='+id+'&something'+something,
            type:"POST",
            success: function(response){
                    alert('caseA done');
            }   
  });
}

function caseBsend(title, id){     //something wrong
     $.ajax({
                  url:'/test/{caseB}.html',
                  data: 'title='+title+'&id='+id+'&somethingelse='+somethingelse,
                  type:"POST",
                  success: function(response){
                                alert('caseB done!');
            }   
     });
}
```

2) myController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value="/test/{caseA}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String caseAHandler(@RequestBody String  response) {
      …
      ...
}

@RequestMapping(value="/test/{caseB}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String caseBHandler(@RequestBody String  response) {
{
    ….
    …
}
```

I have looked other answers something similar for a few days but I couldn't really cleared it out. what I am doing incorrect here?

maybe it is so obvious or simple to someone knows well about this world. but I can't clear it out why both posts goes to the same method even with different url. I am really appreciated if someone clear this out.

Comment: please clarify what is url:'/test/{caseA}.html' in your jsp

Comment: actually the other value was writing mistake. I don't think It should be any meaningful (clarify) text for url , because as long as it matches with `value="/test/{caseA}"` in the method caseAHandler in myController.java . so I don't think I need to clarify what is `/test/{caseA}.html'`. It matches with `value="/test/{caseA}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Value in {} is a URL placeholder. So your caseAHandler will react on any /test/a, /test/bb, etc. URLs.

If you need separate handlers react on separate URL try to remove {}.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/test/caseA", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@RequestMapping(value="/test/caseB", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

And same in your JSP